# One to many relation and subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, subquery, one-to-many

I have a table `persons(id, fist, last)` and another table `properties(person_id, property_name, property_value)`.

Each person may have many (undefined) properties, the name of these properties can vary based on the favorites of users. For example, for these records, we want the following output:

```
properties
==========
person_id  property_name  property_value
----------------------------------------
1          Gender         Male
1          Education      Under

person
======
id  first  last
----------------
1   John   Smith

result
======
id  First  Last   Gender  Education
-----------------------------------
1   John   Smith  Male    Under
```

Is there an easy way to have this done without using several steps in querying the db? I mean using subqueries, join, group by, or any other means necessary to do the job?

PS.I am using sqlite2&3

Thank you,

Mahmoud

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add the code what you have tried & others will help...

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```sql
SELECT
  pers.id,
  pers.first,
  pers.last,
  gender.property_value AS gender,
  edu.property_value AS education
FROM person pers
LEFT JOIN properties gender 
  ON (gender.person_id = pers.id AND gender.property_name = 'Gender') 
LEFT JOIN properties edu
  ON (edu.person_id = pers.id AND edu.property_name = 'Education')
```

But there is no way to do this for an arbitrary number of columns. You need to know which columns you want and join accordingly.

What you *can* do, is build a query dynamically beforehand in another language, and then execute that. If you do so, *please* use parameters. Please?

If you want, you can create a view showing all properties for person_ids:

```sql
CREATE VIEW all_properties (
  person_id,
  gender,
  education
)
AS SELECT
  pers.person_id,
  gender.property_value,
  edu.property_value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM properties) pers
LEFT JOIN properties gender 
  ON (gender.person_id = pers.person_id AND gender.property_name = 'Gender') 
LEFT JOIN properties edu
  ON (edu.person_id = pers.person_id AND edu.property_name = 'Education')
```

But that's not going to make much difference.

Comment: Thank you very much SQB. That's what I want.

Comment: and for arbitrary number of columns, I can use a loop in my programming language to build the variable portion of the query. Then execute the final query on database.

Comment: That is indeed an option. What I meant to say was that there is no way to do this in _just_ SQL.

Comment: Is it possible to make an intermediary view to build a new table with property_names as column names and then run query on it

Comment: Nope. A view is more or less a codified query, so if it's not doable in a query, its not doable in a view either. There is something else you can do, I'll add that to my answer.